# Can't get image to change on keypress on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to make it so that when I press left, it shows the image set for going left. (I'm making an RPG game.) I can't figure out how to use a spritesheet, so I ended up loading each image individually to make things easier.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <script>
        function initCanvas(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas')
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

          //Variables
          var cw = canvas.width;
          var ch = canvas.height;
          var x = 20;
          var y = 20;
          var width = 40;
          var height = 40;


                //----------------
                //Char (Spritesheet soon)
                //----------------
                    var charup = new Image();
                    charup.src = "up.png";

                    var chardown = new Image();
                    chardown.src = "down.png";

                    var charleft = new Image();
                    charleft.src = "left.png";

                    var charright = new Image();
                    charright.src = "right.png";


                // 
                draw(); //Executes the Draw Function
                //

                //-------------
                //WASD Controls
                //-------------
                document.addEventListener("keydown", move, false);

                function move(event){

                        if(event.keyCode == 87){ //w

                        ctx.drawImage(charup, x, y, width, height);
                                if(y >= 20){
                                        y-=20;

                                }
                                else if(y < 20){
                                        y = 460;
                                }
                        }
                        if(event.keyCode == 65){ //a

                        ctx.drawImage(charleft, x, y, width, height);
                                if(x >= 20){
                                        x-=20;
                                }
                                else if(x < 20){
                                        x = 460;
                                }
                        }
                        if(event.keyCode == 83){ //s
                        ctx.drawImage(chardown, x, y, width, height);
                                if(y+height <= 490){
                                        y+=20;
                                }
                                else if(y+height > 460){
                                        y = 0;
                                }
                        }
                        if(event.keyCode == 68){ //d
                        ctx.drawImage(charright, x, y, width, height);
                                if(x+width <= 490){
                                        x+=20;
                                }
                                else if(x+width > 490){
                                        x = 0;
                                }
                        }

                    draw();

                    //Idea for sprite: If press right it goes right and loads a gif while going right...
                    //And when "keyup" or keyrelease or whatever, it stops the animation
                    //Or loads a neutral one facing the same direction.

             }

             //--------------
             //Draw Function
             //--------------
                function draw(){
                //Clears rect for animation purposes
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

                ctx.fillStyle = "green";
                        //ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
                ctx.drawImage(chardown, x, y, width, height);
                }

        }

        //------------
        //Game Loop
        //------------
     window.addEventListener('load', function(event){
        initCanvas();
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Irrelevant, but I'm trying to make a little rouge-like-rpg-game-thing, or just some small rpg where I can kill something... (or something...) Just thought it'd brighten the mood, or perhaps even help somehow.

Comment: I ended up changing some of the code. I made it try to draw the character after seeing if you are in a specific coord... this is wrong because I want it to draw it either way. Still doesn't work, but I updated the main code. TLDR; I moved a line or 2, but it did nothing.

Comment: Try making a new image variable `var player = new Image()` and put its source to blank `player.src = ""`. The next thing you do is if W is pressed: `player.src=charup.src` and so on for all button presses. in your draw function, simply draw your player-image: `ctx.drawImage(player, x, y, width, height);`

Comment: I knew there was a way to do that, but wasn't sure how. I'll try it out, and I'll keep you posted... You should try posting that as the answer that way I can mark it.

Comment: IT WORKED! Please post it as the answer, that way I can mark you as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the draw-function that reserts the character image on each draw.

The solution would be to declare a new variable that will host the current picture for your character:

```
var imgPlayer = new Image();
imgPlayer.src = "down.png"; //This is your default image.
```

Next step is to alter your keylistener-function so that the source for your player-image is changed (also remove all drawing of your character in this function). Like so:

```
if(event.keyCode == 87){ //w
    imgPlayer.src = charup.src;
    //the rest of your code...
}
```

Finally, in your draw-function:

```
ctx.drawImage(imgPlayer, x, y, width, height);
```

**-----HERE ENDS THE ANSWER, STUFF BELOW ARE JUST FOR FUN-------**

For fun, here's an unfinished game I started with a while back.
http://home.niddro.com/HTML5/supergoose/SuperGoose.html
The character's feet have 3 images that loop as the players moves him. I based that idea on the super mario bros concept.
[image: Mario 3-part sprite]

Fun fact 2:
In [another game](http://home.niddro.com/HTML5/bunny/game.html) I made a bunny run really fast by looping 2 images of blurred feet:
[image: bunny][image: bunnyfeet1][image: bunnyfeet2]