# Make an image appear and then grow in size in a html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I was wondering if its possible to create an image using various lines and bez-curves that appears and then moves down the canvas and gets larger as it grows. The animation in question requires the room to fill with gas and so the the gas gets greater and greater as it moves around the canvas.

I had thought about just drawing the image and then using a for loop to move the image down until a certain y coordinate, but this doesnt help with the increasing part of the created image

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to make animations happen. What I normally do for my canvas games is that I have a gameloop that loops at a certain FPS that I decide at the start of my project. Each animation is normally controlled by time an speed.

```
var fps = 60;
var lastUpdateTime = +new Date(); //when did I last update the game?

function gameloop() {
    var updateStartTime = +new Date();
    update(updateStartTime-lastUpdateTime); //update the game for the according to the elapsed time since last update
    lastUpdateTime = updateStartTime;

    //Normally I also handle spawning stuff here
    //I also remove old object in my gameloop

    setTimeout(gameloop,1000/fps)
}

function update(elapsedTime) {
    //This function update the locations of game elements such as player position, bullets, enemies, bananas etc. (or even gas clouds!)
    //When I change a value, I use the time-parameter passed along with the call so that I get a smooth game even though the browser might lag.
    playerX += velocity*timeElapsed; //as an example
}
```

Here's an example on your problem where I made a function to create a gas bubble object (yes, I do know how wrong it is to use gas **bubbles** =P). These objects travel downwards (physics?!) and increase in size (OK, this is starting to sound more and more crazy), just have a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/Niddro/ppa4xuw8/

Comment: This is really cool, thanks. It has given me a good idea of how i can go about this. In regards to your animation, how would you stop the bubbles at a certain 'y co-ordinate'.

Comment: When a bubble reaches a critical y-coordinate, you can stop it by putting its velocity to 0. `gasBubbles[i].velocity = 0;` Perform the check (if-statement) inside the for-loop in the update()-function.

Comment: Excellent i think i have got exactly what i needed. If i wanted to run another animation at the same time as the bubbles moving down the screen using setInterval, could i just add that in as a seperate function and call it somewhere in the gameloop()? I have a man that walks and eventually falls down due to the gas, however im using setInterval to loop through the different images of the man to simulate his movement and its not quite appearing properly

Comment: This sounds like a new question, submit it and I'll be happy to help. Challanging to do this in comments =)  Perhaps the answer to your new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28432148/2180252

Comment: Thanks alot, i have posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919789/canvas-animations-running-at-the-same-time-using-both-raf-and-setinterval As always any help appreciated